# Strncat copied to the destination with an offset

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, exploit

So am trying to disassemble this simple c program on strncat ,

```
 #include <string.h>

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {  
    char buf[128];
    strncat(buf,argv[1],sizeof(buf));    
   }
```

After disassembling it

[image]

So the thing is the string in argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDxHk.png) is to be copied to [rbp-0x80] 
rsi has a pointer to argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDxHk.png) and rdi is [rbp-0x80]

[rbp-0x80]  is 0x7fffffffe0d0 in my case

this is the input that I pass as argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDxHk.png) `perl -e 'print "B"x10;print "A"x118'`

so 0x7fffffffe0d0 - 0x7fffffffe0da are supposed to Have 4242... 
but there is an address stored from 0x7fffffffe0d5 - 0x7fffffffe0d0

Here is the screen shot before calling strncat function 
[image]

Here is the screen shot after calling strncat function
[image]

I don't get why the String starts from 0x7fffffffe0d6 rather than 0x7fffffffe0d0
[image]

Any ideas ?

EDIT :

Screen shot with inputs 
[image]

Comment: @PeterCordes thats what I thought , So I printed the string using printf 
For the input string hello I am Getting Hello as output and if i have 
`perl -e 'print"A"x15' I get 15 A but after 16 I get  �����AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Any ideas ? Ill update the question with the screen shot .

Comment: So you're actually using `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...` as the arg, not `perl -e 'print...`?  i.e. you're using the output of the perl command, not the text of the perl command like your question says?  backquotes are the stackoverflow markdown for `code`.  You should say you're using `$(perl -e ...)` as the arg.

Comment: But anyway, non-ascii garbage near the start of `buf` is exactly what your gdb dump shows is there.  Why is any of this surprising?  It would be easier to read if you dumped in byte-size chunks, rather than words (since x86 is little-endian).  The last (least significant) byte of each 32bit hex value is the first byte in memory order.

Comment: @PeterCordes
perl -e 'print "A"x10' produces 10 A , just to easy things off :) 
just wondering why for string Hello (and input less than 16byte ) the output is without garbage

Comment: gcc emits code that keeps the stack 16B-aligned.  Probably a longer arg string takes up that much more space on the stack, and that's the threshold where `rsp` bumps down by 16B inside `main`.  So `buf[]` has different uninitialized garbage.

Comment: Also, you should be running as root.  [That's just a bad idea.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192422/118588).  Create a user account for yourself.

Comment: I know what `perl` does.  But look at your question.  There aren't backquotes around it in the text of your question, because backquotes are a markdown formatting character.  So they didn't appear literally in your question, making it look like you were saying you used `perl ...` as the actual arg.  That's why I suggested you should have written `$(perl -e ...)`, because it's clearer, [and `$()` is better anyway](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: @PeterCordes Haha yeah I know running as root is a bad idea , its running on a VM  :) 
Yeah the '`' got lost ,  sorry for that my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't initialize `buf[]`, and the uninitialized garbage in it happens not to start with a `0`.  You used `strncat`, not `strncpy`, so it looks for the start of the existing string.  Fortunately there is a zero near the start of the buffer, so you don't actually overflow it.  (Which is possible because you used `strncat` wrong).

Surprisingly, neither gcc nor clang know enough about strncat to warn about reading uninitialized data.  [clang-3.8 does warn that you got the size wrong](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm+-pedantic',source:'%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main(int+argc,+char+**argv)+%7B++%0A++++char+buf%5B128%5D%3B%0A++++strncat(buf,argv%5B1%5D,sizeof(buf))%3B++++%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3):

[`strncat` doesn't include the terminating `0` in the count, but it always writes one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncat.3.html) (unlike `strncpy`).  And the count doesn't include `strlen(dst)`, either.  **The count is the max number of chars it will read from the source**, not the size of the dest buffer.

Comment: Yeah thats the Issue :D , when before strncat is called the  0x7fffffffe0d0 had 7ffffffffe250 which was ending with a null char , so it got appended to it . Now the issue is while running it normally ie ./a.out hello , i get hello
when i run it with gdb i get the junk value o.O